# Want to store multiple id's (dynamically) in session array of Codeignitor 2.x

Tags: codeigniter-2, array-push, codeigniter-datamapper

Need to store multiple id's dynamically in codeignitor session array. Array push seems to be not working. Am able to add only one id. Any help?

Code is below:

```
$internships_array['internships'][] = $internship_result['id'];
if (empty($this->session->userdata('internships')) || sizeof($this->session->userdata('internships')) < 1) {
    $this->session->set_userdata($internships_array);
} else {
    array_push($this->session->userdata('internships'), $internship_result['id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using array push in session get all the data in session to an array then update the array after that set session this will work

```
$internships_array['internships'][] = $internship_result['id'];
$insert_to_session=array();
if (!empty($this->session->userdata('internships')) || sizeof($this->session->userdata('internships')) >0) {
  $insert_to_session [‘internships’]= $this->session->userdata('internships');

}

array_push($insert_to_session [‘internships’], $internship_result['id']);

 $this->session->set_userdata($internships_array);
```